# php preg_replace frustration

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Im reluctant to ask but I cant figure out php preg_replace and ignore certain bits of the sting.

```
$string = '2012042410000102';
```

$string needs to look like _0424_102

The showing numbers are variable always changing and 2012 changes ever year

what I've tried:

```
^\d{4}[^\d{4}]10000[^\d{3}]$
^\d{4}[^\d]{4}10000[^\d]{3}$
```

Any help would be appreciated. I know it's a noob question but easy points for whoever helps.

Thanks

Comment: Essentially, you want to replace the first four digits and "10000" with underscores?

Comment: If you write `[^\d]` it means to match non-decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
^\d{4}|10000(?=\d{3}$)
```

This will match either the first four digits in a string, or the string '10000' if there are three digits after '10000' before the end of the string.

You would use it like this:

```
preg_replace('/^\d{4}|10000(?=\d{3}$)/', '_', $string);
```

http://codepad.org/itTgEGo4

Comment: how would you do two delimiters? a blank space for the first part 2012 and an _ for the 100000?

Comment: @knittledan - For that you would probably need to use something like Kolink's solution, where you match the entire string and use capturing groups to keep the portions that you don't want removed.

Answer (score 3):

Your first regex is looking for:

- The start of the string
- Four digits (the year)
- ***Any single character that is not a digit nor { or }***
- The number 10000
- ***Any single character that is not a digit nor { or }***
- The end of the string

Your second regex is looking for:

- The start of the string
- Four digits (the year)
- ***Any four characters that are not digits***
- The number 10000
- ***Any three characters that are not digits***
- The end of the string

The regex you're looking for is:

```
^\d{4}(\d{4})10000(\d{3})$
```

And the replacement should be:

```
_$1_$2
```

This regex looks for:

- The start of the string
- Four digits (the year)
- Capture four digits (the month and day)
- The number 10000
- Capture three digits (the `102` at the end in your example)
- The end of the string

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple string functions:

```
$string = '2012042410000102';
$new = '_'.str_replace('10000', '_', substr($string, 4));
```

http://codepad.org/elRSlCIP

Answer (score 0):

If they're always in the same character locations, regular expressions seem unnecessary. You could use substrings to get the parts you want, like

```
sprintf('_%s_%s', substr($string,4,4), substr($string,13))
```

or

```
'_' . substr($string,4,4) . '_' . substr($string,13)
```